# Implementing Task Farm messaging pattern with zeromq

Tags: php, c++, python, c, zeromq

I am using [zeromq](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Chapter-Four-Reliable-Request-Reply) to solve a problem which involves several hundred (potentially thousands) clients request tasks to be carried out. Each client would request for a specific task to be carried out, and the result(s), when completed, whould be returned back to the client that issued that request.

These are the actors that I have identified so far, in the pattern I have come up with:

- Client: this is the actor that requests a unit of work (or 'job') to be carried out
- Controller: this is the actor that loadbalances the 'jobs' accross available engines
- Engine: this is the actor that receives a job request from the controller and publishes the result back to the client.

I still haven't yet worked out how the engine gets the mesage back to the client. I am guessing that one way for this to be implemented using zeromq would be:

> **Client:**
>   PUSH job messages on one socket to Controller   SUBscribe to completed results on PUBlished by Engine, on another
>   socket
>
> **Controller:**
>   PULL job messages from client on one socket   PUBlish job messages to engines on another socket (clearly, this will be a forwarding device)
>
> **Engine:**
>   SUBscribe to job messages on one socket   PUBlish result to another socket

It would be most helpful if someone provide a skeleton/snippet which will show the outline of how this pattern may be implemented, using the zeromq framework.

The code snippet can be in C, C++, PHP, Python or C#

**[[Edit]]**

After reading up on Task Farms (as suggested by akappa). I think this problem can indeed be modelled by a Task Farm. I have modified my original actors accordingly (and changed the title too).

It would still be very useful if someone who is familiar with zeromq, can sketch out a skeleton that would show how I can use the core components to build such a framework.

Comment: The only thing jumping out at me, is that it seems client and worker is the same thing. They both request a unit of work, do it and reply back when it is done.

Comment: @CodeReaper: Not exactly - perhaps my original question was not well formed. I have updated the question after akappa pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a variety of approaches to this, and [IPython.parallel](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel) includes two such implementations with ZeroMQ - one simple and pure-zmq, and another that is more elaborate, with the Controller implemented in Python.

We split the Controller into two actors:

1. **Hub** - an out-of-the-way process that sees all traffic, and keeps track of the state of the cluster, pushing results to a database, etc., notifying clients about engine connect/disconnect, etc.
2. **Scheduler** - at its core, a simple ROUTER-DEALER device that forwards requests from the client(s) to the engines, and the replies back up.

Looking at just the task-farming part of our topology:

- Scheduler is a 0MQ Queue device, with a ROUTER and DEALER socket, both of which bind.
- Clients have DEALER sockets, connected to the Scheduler's ROUTER
- Engines have ROUTER sockets connected to the Scheduler's DEALER

Which makes use of these two properties:

- DEALERS LRU load-balance requests across peers
- ROUTERs use identity prefixes to send replies back to the peer that made a particular request.

A toy load-balanced task farm with pyzmq, which routes replies back up to the requesting client: https://gist.github.com/1358832

An alternative, where the results go somewhere, but not back up to the requesting client, is the [Ventilator-Sink pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Divide-and-Conquer) in the 0MQ Guide.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classical master/slave parallel pattern (also known as "Farm" or "Task Farm").

There are billion ways to implement it.
[Here](http://www.dhpc.adelaide.edu.au/workshops/CSSM/examples/taskfarm/MPItaskfarm.html) there is a way to implement it using MPI, maybe it can be inspirational to you for implementing it in zeromq.

Comment: +1 for identifying the pattern that models this problem. I have looked at the link you provided and am studying the code. In the event that no one is able to come up with a snippet/outline that shows how to use zeromq to implement this pattern, I will accept your answer by default.